# Traduction en français du mot "frame-up"

Tags: traduction, anglais

1. Je suis un interprète chinois. Je suis tombé dans ma conférence sur la traduction d'un mot chinois qui se traduit parfaitement par "*framing*" en anglais.

> *The defendant was framed (ensared) by police in an attempt of reprisal against media workers who speak out.*

2. Ma tentative de traduction :

   Tout ce que je peux envisager en français, c'est :

> l'accusé a été piégé par la police

3. Ma question:

   Ça me parait correct, mais le problème est que l'original est plus juridique que les verbes *to frame* et *piéger*. Qu'est ce qu'un avocat dirait devant un juge, conformément au vocabulaire juridique, le "délit de *to frame sb*, *de piéger quelqu'un". Par exemple : le délit de piéger un journaliste est passable d'une peine de 10 ans de prison" en anglais et en français ?

Comment: Dans la phrase, il n'est pas question du "*délit de* piéger quelqu'un" mais de la "police qui piège quelqu'un", je me trompe ? Cela fait une grosse différence en termes de traduction surtout si l'on veut être exact juridiquement. Il faudrait savoir lequel des deux est le sens recherché.

Comment: Bonjour, merci de votre réponse. en fr il faudrait etre plus spécifique, mais pas en chinois: le mot original 陷害 se référerait au simple fait d'un délit de "tendre un piège à qn pour le seul but de l'accuser du crime" et l'auteur peut etre n'importe qui, quie ce soit un agent de police ou non. Ex: il a été 陷害 [piégé, was set up] pour harcèlemnt sexuel" par un agent de police, ou un collègue.

Comment: Merci, je comprends mieux. Effectivement, il n'existe pas de verbe avec ce sens précis en français.

Comment: Du coup j'ai un doute, est-ce qu'il s'agit nécessairement d'une fausse accusation montée de toutes pièces ? Ou cela peut être l'utilisation opportuniste par la police d'un véritable délit commis par quelqu'un qu'elle veut piéger (*frame* en anglais est aussi ambigü sur ce point)?

Comment: @guillaume31: c'est le plutot 1er cas: il s'agit purement d' un piège tendu pour jetter le victime au prison. le sens existe dans les 3 langues seulement il existe en chinois un term juridique dédié à ce crime, très proche de la calomnie, defamation, mais avec la nuance que celui-là est plus que de paroles. merci de votre temps et attention

Comment: frame and framed are basically colloquial. The noun frame up is less used than the verb.

Comment: @Lambie: *frame* and *framed* have the translations *cadre* and *encadré*. If you use *frame-up* it's perfectly clear what the question is about.

Comment: @PeterShor No, I was framed by the police is certainly not encadré. The text says the guy was framed. I am just pointing out that frame up would not work in the sentence and that in **English** we usually use the verb.  Why does it bother you that I want to provide additional info? Also, it is slang. You must be kidding when you tell me the translations of frame into French.

Comment: @Lambie Note _to frame up_ can also be a verbal phrase.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t I know that frame up is a noun or phrasal verb. But that was not my point. My point that was one, it is slang and two, the verb is used in the example, not the noun. We usually say: He was framed. There was a frame up. But we would not say: He was framed up, ***usually***. Now, you have repeated the typo: frame up and not: frameup.

Comment: @Lambie _Frameup_ makes the subject of the question more obvious when it stands by itself in a listing. The nuance you make would be better suited for an answer. Wiktionary is the only one standard source which considers _frameup_ as an alternative spelling. This is a valid reason to edit this so if you're sure about this you may do that.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t There is no word in English: frameup. The spelling is: frame-up [more British] and frame up [more AmE]. If you edit a question, you should fix the spelling. The spelling is wrong to any native English speaker. Why  argue about it??

Comment: @Lambie If you edit a question, you should think it through and not do it just to steer it according to your comment. I'm not arguing about it, I've approved the proposed change but I do verify statements which is why I discussed wiktionary. Just like I checked for the verbal phrase. If you think I don't take your statements at face value, then you are right.

Comment: \@Lambie: The standard spelling is *frame-up* in both [American](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frame-up) and [British](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/frame-up) English, as you would know if you looked in a dictionary. And this is French.SE; I don't know why you're arguing about English spelling.

Comment: Firstly, comments are not for extended discussion, which this is clearly becoming. **Take it to chat.** #2: everyone here is very familiar with our [our code of conduct](https://french.stackexchange.com/conduct). Unwelcoming, abusive, and hostile conduct [will not be tolerated here](https://french.stackexchange.com/conduct/abusive-behavior).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sense of "entrapment", the usual terms are "incitation à un crime/délit/infraction", what gives :

*L'accusé a été incité par la police à commettre une tentative de
représailles contre les personnels des médias qui s'expriment.*

In Europe, such deceptive or unfair practices are highly regulated, specially if the crime wouldn't have been committed if the police didn't provoke it.
*Refer to [Dalloz : principe de loyauté dans l’administration de la preuve](https://actu.dalloz-etudiant.fr/a-la-une/article/retour-sur-les-provocations-policieres/h/b5410119ff04b802340da9d1be5b5ac8.html/)*

> En France, le principe de la loyauté de la preuve s'oppose également à
> l'admission des preuves obtenues sur provocations policières (Crim. 27
> févr. 1996). Ce principe vaut pour toutes les enquêtes, qu'elles
> soient le fait d'autorités françaises ou étrangères (Crim. 7 févr.
> 2007). La chambre criminelle opère une distinction entre :
>
> – provocation à la preuve, destinée à faire apparaître la preuve d'une
> infraction qui se serait de toute façon commise sans son intervention
> ;
>
> – et, provocation à l'infraction qui, sans leur intervention, n'aurait
> pas eu lieu.

Comment: merci, c'est bp plus proche je crois.

Comment: Right on, I think this is what I've been looking for. thanks

Comment: Je suis en désaccord avec ta traduction. Ma compréhension de la phrase, et je crois qu'elle est juste, c'est que c'est la police qui agit en représailles contre les journalistes en piégeant cet individu qui fait partie de ce groupe. Ta phrase dit que c'est l'accusé qui est incité par la police à agir contre des journalistes. Je ne crois pas que le texte anglais dit ça.

Comment: @LetterQuest J'ai aussi un doute, je pense qu'on est sur une infraction voisine mais pas la même. Dans ce qui semble être la phrase d'origine en chinois, il ne s'agit pas de pousser au crime mais de fabriquer des preuves.

Comment: merci,  vous avez raison: en original, l'auteur du crime c'est la police qui fabrique des preuves, ou tend un piège ( planting drugs in his car ) pour incrimner le victime. la réponse semble introduit un tiers dans le coup. ai-je bien compris? incitation correspond en ch plutot à 唆使 pousser qn , tandis que 陷害 plutot incrimer qn par un coup monté. Merci

Answer (score 6):

***Piégé*** correspond bien à ce qui est décrit.

Comme synonymes, on peut aussi dire qu'il a été ***dupé, abusé, trompé, manipulé***...

Il s'agit d'un ***coup monté***, d'une ***manipulation***. S'il y a eu des fausses preuves fabriquées par la police, on pourra aussi parler de ***faux par un dépositaire de l'autorité publique dans l'exercice de ses fonctions*** - [Article 441-4 du code pénal](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000006418759).

Answer (score 4):

Il n'existe pas de verbe en français avec le sens "piéger par de fausses accusations". "Piéger" peut très bien vouloir dire placer un suspect dans une situation qui révèle ses crimes réels. C'est problématique si l'on cherche un équivalent exact du verbe chinois.

Néanmoins la deuxième partie de la phrase : *in an attempt to ...* lève l'ambiguité dans ce cas précis, on peut donc tenter d'utiliser "piéger" tel quel.

> L'accusé a été piégé par la police lors d'un acte de
> rétorsion de cette dernière contre les employés de médias qui font des révélations
> publiques.

Au-delà d'un verbe, plusieurs expressions peuvent avoir un sens voisin : "coup monté", "fausses accusations", "machination"... mais les qualifications légales qui peuvent en découler sont multiples, sans correspondance directe et ne remplaceront la plupart du temps pas ces expressions.

Comment: Merci de votre explication en détails.

Comment: Ou: La police a monté un coup contre x. frame en anglais, c'est de l'argot.

Comment: @Lambie bien vu, je n'y avais pas pensé !

Answer (score 2):

Le libellé des infractions varie d'un pays à l'autre ou d'un système juridique à l'autre. Par exemple au Canada, amener un agent de la paix à commencer ou continuer une enquête, en faisant une fausse déclaration qui accuse une personne ou en rapportant une infraction qui n'a pas eu lieu constitue un « [méfait public](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/fra/lois/c-46/section-140.html) », mais parler d'un « méfait public » ne permettra pas de faire comprendre qu'il y a eu un « coup monté » usuellement. Avec l'[infraction](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/fra/lois/c-46/page-20.html) de « parjure », essentiellement un faux témoignage, ou de « fabrication de preuve », on ne réussit pas à englober l'ensemble des gestes préalables à une procédure judiciaire dont on vient de parler. On pourrait parler de « fausses accusations », mais ce n'est ni le libellé d'un délit au Canada, ni exactement ce dont on parle dans la question et est-on exactement « victime de fausses accusations » en termes de tournure ; pas vraiment. Il n'y aura pas nécessairement de correspondance technique exacte. Il faut le plus possible faire ressortir le nom ou le verbe de la langue source, mettre entre parenthèse le nom exact du délit de la langue source et le numéro d'article de l'instrument juridique qui le désigne. C'est du côté du pays source qu'il faut regarder pour voir comment on a choisi de traduire, comme il s'agit de traduction spécialisée. On peut comparer la structure de plusieurs instruments et voir la catégorie de délit et procéder par recoupement et inférence mais c'est plutôt risqué.

Comment: Merci bien de votre explication en détails

Comment: DeepL dit « (avoir été) accusé à tort » pour un contexte comme : « 囚犯声称他受到了仇人的诬陷 » (_The prisoner claimed that he had been framed up by his enemies_).

Answer (score 0):

Un avocat pourrait parler de *coup monté judiciaire* ; il semble n'y avoir sur la Toile pas plus de deux références dans lesquelles ce terme soit utilisé (voir ci-dessous); comme ce type de délit est très peu courant il n'y a pas de terme juridique traditionnel ; par exemple, le dictionnaire juridique de [Gérard  Cornu](https://insidercambodia.asia/files/Vocabulaire%20juridique%20by%20G%C3%A9rard%20Cornu%20(z-lib.org).pdf) ne le mentionne pas ; on n'y trouve pas non plus « coup monté ». Ces termes ne figurent pas non plus dans le [Code Pénal](https://codes.droit.org/PDF/Code%20p%C3%A9nal.pdf).

([Invité Afrique - Affaire Biram: « C'est un coup monté judiciaire» selon l'avocat du prévenu](https://www.rfi.fr/fr/emission/20180816-affaire-abeid-est-coup-monte-judiciaire-selon-avocat-prevenu))  Vous dites « décision de justice », mais il faut savoir de quelle justice on parle. Au vu des éléments qui sont en ma possession, et je suis en contact évidemment avec l’ensemble des personnes concernées, c’est une plainte totalement fabriquée. C’est un coup monté judiciaire avec un journaliste qui, de façon complaisante, évidemment en lien, sinon aux ordres du pouvoir politique, a mis en œuvre cette stratégie de criminalisation, de persécution, d’intimidation à l’encontre de Biram.

([Détention arbitraire et coup monté judiciaire contre les dirigeants paysans membres de CNA](https://cloc-viacampesina.net/detention-arbitraire-et-coup-monte-judiciaire-contre-les-dirigeants-paysans-de-cna)) Communiqué de solidarité et dénonciation publique de détention arbitraire et coup monté judiciaire contre les dirigeants paysans membres de la coordination nationale agraire – cna – organisation membre de la cloc lvc colombie

> L'accusé a été victime d'un coup monté judiciaire. (*Il n'y a pas besoin de mentionner la police immédiatement, bien que cela soit nécessaire par la suite puisque la magistrature et la police judicaire font partie du pouvoir judiciaire.*)

Comment: Tu sembles confondre la justice et la police.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne parle pas de police mais de police judiciaire,  c'est à dire de l'organisation qui est sous le  contrôle de la magistrature (procureur), et qui sert la magistrature dans le but d'établir les faits. (Une information judiciaire est ouverte quand un juge d'instruction est chargé d'une enquête pénale. L'enquête pénale est une phase de la procédure pendant laquelle la police judiciaire recherche les auteurs des infractions et tente de rassembler les preuves. https://www.demarches.interieur.gouv.fr/particuliers/information-judiciaire)

Comment: Note que ces réalités dont tu parles n'existent pas au Canada, où on parle aussi français. Elles sont tributaires du système inquisitoire qui diffère mécaniquement du système contradictoire, pour des résultats similaires.